# Make image move more "fluidly"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I want to make an `IBAction` that when called makes an image move a certain amount of pixels "fluidly." I have one now that make the image move 10 pixels to the left but it just kind of teleports there. I want the image to move over, almost like its walking not magically ending up there.

here is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)moveImageLeft:(id)sender
{
    y = y + 10;
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 45, 56);   
}
```

Comment: Check out animations. I don't work with iOS, but `UIView`'s `beginAnimation:` etc. may be worth a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

y = y + 10;
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 45, 56);        
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 5):

@Dimple's answer is correct. However, just for reference purposes, here's another way of doing it. It's called an animation block and in my opinion makes the whole animation process a lot easier.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    y = y + 10;
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 45, 56);
}completion:^(BOOL finishedAnimating){
    if (finishedAnimating == YES) {
        NSLog(@"animation finished");//you can put your own completion handler events here
    }
}];
```

Comment: What exactly does it help with?

Comment: @user1438042 It does everything the same, I just think it's a cleaner and more organized way of performing an animation.

Comment: +1 The docs clearly say to use the block based animation methods for iOS4+